# Properly choosing React keys while rendering items from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

I've been recently studying the importance of elements' keys in React and I'm still a little confused about it.

I have this case where there is datagrid component responsible for presenting data in rows. There is implemented sorting, filtering and pagination. I fetch the rows data from api.

And the question is:
How should I properly choose keys for map function elements (rows)?

The thing is that the already fetched row data can change between refreshes (by being edited by other user).

Should I use unique ids for key properties (for instance nanoid) or use row.id?

If I understand it correctly, using row.id would result in no row rerendering for already loaded rows even if some of row data were changed.
On the other hand, using unique ids (like nanoid) would make negative impact on performance while sorting, filtering etc...?

Do I get this right, and how to do this properly then?

Comment: Most importantly you should choose a **stable** key. Something that is unique to the row that will not change. ID's are a perfect choice for this.

Comment: *If I understand it correctly, using row.id would result in no row rerendering for already loaded rows even if some of row data were changed.* - This is not correct. It only means React can correctly identify your row when deciding if it needs to re-render/mount/un-mount. Normal re-rendering rules apply, and it will re-render if state or props change.

Comment: I usually concatenate a word describing the item itself and the index (from a `.map(item, index)`) of it, for instance: `<tr key={\`row-${indexrow} \`}>` and `<td key={\`cell-${indexCell}\`}>` . But if you have any `cell.id` or `row.id` go ahead and add it, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree to study the key in more details. Here's my understanding.

> If I understand it correctly, using row.id would result in no row rerendering for already loaded rows even if some of row data were changed.

This is not true, the purpose of the key is to identify the item location, so when it comes to the reconciliation (convert element into a node), *React* knows if a node (fiber) can be reused to speed up the update process.

Let's make an example, if initially the the key order is

```
  1 2 3
```

And somehow after a re-order, it becomes the following in the new update

```
  2 1 3
```

Then *React* is guided to use the node with key 1 to update the item. The item is updated, and in this case, to the right place. BTW, *React* doesn't know by default the order of items, to *React*, they look all similar ;)

I'm only giving you a basic case. But you can make a guess for other cases, ex. with one key missing, or a new key added.

Comment: "This is not true, the purpose of the key is to identify the item location, so when it comes to the reconciliation (convert element into a node), React knows if a node (fiber) can be reused to speed up the update process." Thanks. This is the thing I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Keys should always be unique, stable (as mentioned above by Brian), and never manipulated in your code (hence stable).

A unique ID is preferred. I've seen people pass an entire `user` object as the key. Let along that there *might be* duplicate users, this could also be an **enormous** key.

[Do not use the index of any array as your key.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)